# How to escape spaces in library path appended to LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: linux, unix, ld-preload

I'm having a problem with LD_PRELOAD on Linux. I'm trying to load a library existing in a directory with spaces in its name, right before launching my application:

```
> export LD_PRELOAD='/home/myuser/MyApp\ Test/lib/mylib.so'
```

However, the path is not being taken properly. It gets split where the space exists, so it tries to preload these:

```
ERROR: ...: object '/home/myuser/MyApp' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored
ERROR: ...: object 'Test/lib/mylib.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored
```

I'm already escaping the space in 'MyApp Test'. What is the correct way to pass such path?

Edit: exporting without the escaped space as suggested, renders the same results:

> export LD_PRELOAD='/home/myuser/MyApp Test/lib/mylib.so'

As well as (no quotes, just escaped space):

> export LD_PRELOAD=/home/myuser/MyApp\ Test/lib/mylib.so

Comment: Try without the backslash: `export LD_PRELOAD='/home/myuser/MyApp Test/lib/mylib.so'`

Comment: I tried without the backslash, but it gives the same problem. The library path is divided in two

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dynamic loader is probably just doing a naive split on spaces, in which case it's impossible to get it to treat the space as part of your path.

You can work around it by creating a symlink to the library you want to preload that doesn't contain any spaces.

**Edit:**

confirmed by http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1142062

> As other variables like PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, this variable may
>   contain list of library names separated by colons. But... for
>   compatibility with legacy systems it is possible to separate
>   LD_PRELOAD elements by spaces. And older systems did not understand
>   escaping so it turns out it is impossible to put full library paths
>   into LD_PRELOAD if they contain spaces.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually work around this by adding the path with spaces to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then using LD_PRELOAD without the pathname.  For example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myuser/MyApp\ Test/lib/":${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so
```